# How to call different code based on different connections at compile time in LINQPad?

Tags: c#, compilation, linqpad

In LINQPad, the connection to database can be either

1. LINQ to SQL
2. entity frame core
3. others or none

Here is some code I like to write, which saves data based on the different connection. but the predefined symbols do not exist.

```
#if LINQ2SQL
    SubmitChanges();
#elif EFCORE
    SaveChanges();
#else
    ; //None
#endif
```

is there a way to do this? thanks.

<s>(Reflection does not work here, since this need to be decided at compile time.)</s>

**Update**
as [Joe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64888296/2055187) shows, reflection can fix the issue perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason that you don't want to solve this at runtime?

The following will work:

```
if (GetType().GetProperty ("ChangeTracker") != null)
    ((dynamic)this).SaveChanges();     // EF Core
else if (GetType().GetProperty ("Mapping") != null)
    ((dynamic)this).SubmitChanges();   // LINQ to SQL
```